# Is there a SNS function that lists all endpointARNs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Is there a SNS function that can be called inside a Lambda function to retrieve all SNS endpointARNs? Better yet, can it filter endpointARN by the "user data" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll get is the [listEndpointsByPlatformApplication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#listEndpointsByPlatformApplication-property) method of the [SNS client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html) in the [AWS SDK for Node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/).

**Example usage (from the linked documentation):**

```
var params = {
  PlatformApplicationArn: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  NextToken: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
sns.listEndpointsByPlatformApplication(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

**Notes:**

- This API is paginated; every response will contain a max of 100 results and return with a `NextToken` value that you need to pass into subsequent requests to get the next batch. The last page will return a null value for `NextToken`.
- The `data` object in the callback will contain a `map<String>` called `Attributes` that you can parse to filter for only endpoints having the `CustomUserData` attribute.